# Create directory and have all files automatically load everytime

Tags: php, apache, configuration, autoloader

I wanted to set up a config directory where all the files automatically inside this directory will be loaded with every page.

My goal is to put a bunch of functions and defines in there so for example

```
config/index.php
config/defines.php
```

and so and have these files all automatically load every time. Anyone know how i can do that

Comment: With [`glob`](http://php.net/glob), [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) and [`include`](http://php.net/include).

Comment: I haven't quite figured out what [Midgard and PHPCR *does*](http://midgard-project.org/), but maybe it's relevant here? (Feel free anyone to explain otherwise what these are about if this is off-base.)

Comment: By the way, how many config files do you have in there where you don't just want to list them out in the source...?

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = glob('config/*.php');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    include $file;
}
```

Comment: where would i put this in though? Im not too familiar with server set ups such as apache so where would i put this function in?

Comment: Just put it in the top of your `index.php`, or whatever file you're loading first.

Comment: This still requires me to be dependant on a specific file loading though. Say i have a autoload file that i put this function in. How can i get that file to be loaded or included in every single file without manually including it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) function for a simple way of iterating through files in a directory.

Obviously, you will need to make sure that nothing untrusted can add files to that directory.

Comment: where would i put this function in though? What file or directory would i put this in

Comment: @Yevo Wherever you would put the `include` line if you were just including one file. If you want to run it at the top of lots of different files, you could put it in a file of its own and add something like `include 'include_config_files.php';` or `include 'startup.php';`